# Internal Server Error in django and uwsgi + nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I deployed a Django application on server.
I used nginx and uwsgi as web server.
I didn't have any problem first, but I see "Internal Server Error" when I add rest_framework to project. I guess It has problem with rest_framework but I don't know its reason. I think you should know when I remove rest_framework from project, It's working.

I should say when I run project with `python manage.py runserver`, It's working. I guess there are any problems  with nginx or uwsgi.

I put my settings below:

> settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'tagulous',
    'django_render_partial',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # 'easy_thumbnails',
    # 'filer',
    'mptt',
    # 'anymail',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'sitebuilder.apps.SitebuilderConfig',
    'rest_framework',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'boofeh.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sitebuilder','templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sitebuilder','templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'boofeh.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'boofeh',
        'USER': 'boofehuser',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
#         # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
#         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#         'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
#     ),
#     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
#         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly', # if the users haven't logged in then they can use it as read only.
#     )
# }


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

SITE_ID = 1


SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'xml':    'tagulous.serializers.xml_serializer',
    'json':   'tagulous.serializers.json',
    'python': 'tagulous.serializers.python',
    'yaml':   'tagulous.serializers.pyyaml',
}


CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ckeditor/"


CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
    },
}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/users/profile'
```

> /etc/uwsgi/sites/boofeh.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = boofeh
envname = boofehenv
base = /home/
envbase = /root/
uid = root

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(envbase)/Env/%(envname)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/boofeh

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name iranpersianland.com www.iranpersianland.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/boofeh.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/boofeh.error.log debug;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/base/ {
        root /home/boofeh/sitebuilder;
        expires -1;
        sendfile off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/boofeh;
    }


    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/boofeh.sock;
    }
}
```

I use this tutorial: [How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#prerequisites-and-goals)

[image: picture of site on browser]

I use these versions in my project:
 1. Django==2.0.4
 2. djangorestframework==3.8.2

What's the problem? 
Who could help me?

> boofeh.error.log:

```
2018/08/30 07:01:00 [debug] 25677#25677: epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:00002001
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: posix_memalign: 000055715F5AAAF0:512 @16
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 accept: 31.58.254.183:13730 fd:3
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer add: 3: 60000:1535626924708
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http wait request handler
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 malloc: 000055715F5AAD00:1024
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 recv: fd:3 564 of 1024
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 posix_memalign: 000055715F5B58C0:4096 @16
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http process request line
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http uri: "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http args: ""
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http exten: ""
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 posix_memalign: 000055715F5AC890:4096 @16
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http process request header line
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Cookie: trx_addons_is_retina=0; csrftoken=NOWkrU12LMJehQSGPCifvuxet6GlS6lu3O31e0UbUIMzHZtRo6H2B19Wc6cVOLHQ"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [info] 25677#25677: *1 client sent invalid header line: "AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.3" while reading client request headers, client: 31.58.254.183, server: iranpersianland.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Host: 195.201.62.104"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http header done
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer del: 3: 1535626924708
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 generic phase: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 test location: "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 using configuration "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http cl:-1 max:104857600
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 generic phase: 5
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 generic phase: 6
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 generic phase: 7
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 access phase: 8
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 access phase: 9
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 access phase: 10
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 post access phase: 11
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:3 ev:80002005
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "QUERY_STRING"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "QUERY_STRING: "
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "REQUEST_METHOD"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "GET"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "REQUEST_METHOD: GET"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "CONTENT_TYPE"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "CONTENT_TYPE: "
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "CONTENT_LENGTH"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "CONTENT_LENGTH: "
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "REQUEST_URI"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "REQUEST_URI: /"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "PATH_INFO"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "PATH_INFO: /"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "DOCUMENT_ROOT"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "DOCUMENT_ROOT: /usr/share/nginx/html"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "SERVER_PROTOCOL"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "HTTP/1.1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "REQUEST_SCHEME"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "http"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "REQUEST_SCHEME: http"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "REMOTE_ADDR"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "31.58.254.183"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "REMOTE_ADDR: 31.58.254.183"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "REMOTE_PORT"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "13730"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "REMOTE_PORT: 13730"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "SERVER_PORT"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "80"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "SERVER_PORT: 80"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script copy: "SERVER_NAME"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http script var: "iranpersianland.com"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "SERVER_NAME: iranpersianland.com"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: 1"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_COOKIE: trx_addons_is_retina=0; csrftoken=NOWkrU12LMJehQSGPCifvuxet6GlS6lu3O31e0UbUIMzHZtRo6H2B19Wc6cVOLHQ"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_HOST: 195.201.62.104"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 uwsgi param: "HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http cleanup add: 000055715F5B6828
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 get rr peer, try: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 stream socket 12
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 epoll add connection: fd:12 ev:80002005
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 connect to unix:/run/uwsgi/boofeh.sock, fd:12 #2
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 connected
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream connect: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 posix_memalign: 000055715F58BF70:128 @16
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream send request
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream send request body
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 chain writer buf fl:0 s:834
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 chain writer in: 000055715F5B6860
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 writev: 834 of 834
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer add: 12: 60000:1535626924709
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http run request: "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream process header
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 malloc: 000055715F59D8C0:4096
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 recv: fd:12 104 of 4096
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http uwsgi status 500 "500 Internal Server Error"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http uwsgi header: "Connection: close"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http uwsgi header: "Content-Type: text/plain"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http uwsgi header done
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 xslt filter header
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 11:01:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055715F5AD5D0, pos 000055715F5AD5D0, size: 184 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:184
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http cacheable: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream process upstream
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe preread: 21
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 readv: 1, last:3992
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe recv chain: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055715F59D8C0, pos 000055715F59D913, size: 21 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe length: -1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 input buf #0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe write downstream: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe write downstream flush in
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http output filter "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 image filter
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 xslt filter body
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 000055715F5AD7A8
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http chunk: 21
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 posix_memalign: 000055715F590520:4096 @16
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055715F5AD5D0, pos 000055715F5AD5D0, size: 184 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055715F5905A0, pos 000055715F5905A0, size: 4 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055715F59D8C0, pos 000055715F59D913, size: 21 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055715D8DE81E, size: 2 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:211
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 pipe write downstream done
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer: 12, old: 1535626924709, new: 1535626924710
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 finalize http upstream request: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 finalize http uwsgi request
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free rr peer 1 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 close http upstream connection: 12
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F58BF70, unused: 48
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer del: 12: 1535626924709
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http upstream temp fd: -1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http output filter "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 image filter
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 xslt filter body
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 00007FFD35BAF520
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http chunk: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055715F5AD5D0, pos 000055715F5AD5D0, size: 184 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055715F5905A0, pos 000055715F5905A0, size: 4 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055715F59D8C0, pos 000055715F59D913, size: 21 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write old buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055715D8DE81E, size: 2 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055715D8DE81B, size: 5 file: 0, size: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:216
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http write filter limit 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 writev: 216 of 216
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 set http keepalive handler
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http close request
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http log handler
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F59D8C0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F5B58C0, unused: 12
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F5AC890, unused: 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F590520, unused: 3390
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F5AAD00
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 tcp_nodelay
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer add: 3: 65000:1535626929710
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 post event 000055715F5C1450
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 delete posted event 000055715F5C1450
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http keepalive handler
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 malloc: 000055715F5AAD00:1024
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 recv: fd:3 -1 of 1024
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2018/08/30 07:01:04 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F5AAD00
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 event timer del: 3: 1535626929710
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 http keepalive handler
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 close http connection: 3
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2018/08/30 07:02:09 [debug] 25677#25677: *1 free: 000055715F5AAAF0, unused: 112
```

> uwsgi.error.log:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2794)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2796, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2797, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 2798, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 2799, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 2800, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 2796|app: -1|req: -1/1] 162.158.89.228 () {56 vars in 1084 bytes} [Fri Aug 31 21:16:35 2018] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

Comment: Did you ran the migrations ? Can you once try in debugging mode ?

Comment: Please don't post secrets from your settings. I suggest you change your `SECRET_KEY` and any other passwords you included in the question.

Comment: Yes I ran the migrations. What do you mean from  debugging mode? @Umair

Comment: I suggest you start logging https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html error logs are very useful.. as you can clearly see now.. standing there in the dark. Enable logging/ even syslog if you really need it.

Comment: Also, i would try killing nginx, commenting out `socket` and adding `http :80` (do 8080 or something if you dont want to kill nginx) and running uwsgi normally and NOT in deamon mode -- it should spit out errors, errors both us and you can use to lead you to a functional program :D

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#debug

Comment: @AlexJane the secret key is already out there.. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52094338/revisions the internet will forever know, please generate a new one and disgard this one

Comment: there're not any problem when I run "uwsgi --http :8080 --home /project/boofehenv --chdir /project/boofeh -w boofeh.wsgi"
It's working on MY_IP_ADDRESS:8080 @JavierBuzzi
Maybe there is a problem in ngnix, I don't know.

Comment: @AlexJane and when you do `uwsgi --socket /run/uwsgi/boofeh.sock ....` what happens in nginx?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I edited my question, I put nginx's error.log.

Comment: @AlexJane and the uwsgi error logs?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I put uwsgi error logs, tnx for attention

Comment: @AlexJane Looks like a uwsgi issue. So nginx can talk to uwsgi, uwsgi cant seem to locate your wsgi.py file. Look at your file paths/ config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my problem. It caused that I had two environments on server and uwsgi settings was set on another environment that not installing rest framework on it.
thanks everybody

Comment: Hi, I'm running into exactly the same issue, also used the digital ocean instructions. First time with Python, nginx, uwsgi. Any chance you could elaborate on 'two environments'?
I have 2 virtual envs for python and when running uwsgi --http :8000 .... I can server each project correctly. It's only when connecting to nginx I get the 'Internal Server Error'. Trying to activate/find logs but no luck so far. Any pointers appreciated. EDIT: Connect to nginx through sockets which are there /run/uwsgi/<name>